# ms Access runtime error '2115" when setting ListIndex to -1

Tags: ms-access, listbox, runtime-error

I have Find Forms that are basically a large list box with some filter, sorting  and action buttons and some text boxes to implement the filter.

I have been using these forms for quite a while without problem. The SELECT button is disabled unless an item from the list box is selected. I am trying to unselect any listbox entry when the filtering or sorting is changed.

To do this I set the focus to the listbox (no multi selection option) to -1. There are a number of equivalent actions and I have tried most of them. Once ListIndex is set to -1 I get the '2115' runtime error if I execute a  requery action on the listbox or a refresh action on the containing form. In addition, I cannot set the focus to any of the text boxes or buttons on the form getting a variety of runtime errors that say that the field must be saved.

Anybody have an ideas about how this is supposed to function?

In the code snippet the actual code getting the error is the .requery line near the bottom after the Unselect listbox comment

Here is a code snippet of one of the ways I have had this occur:

```
    With Me.lbxFoundItems
        If strCurrentSearchText = vbNullString Then    'Nothing to search for
            .Visible = False
            Call ButtonSettings
            Exit Sub
        End If
        strQry = strSql & strWhere & strOrderBy
        If Nz(.RowSource, vbNullString) = vbNullString Then       'First time through
            Set qry = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set qry = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(strQname, strQry)
            If qry Is Nothing Then
                Set qry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(strQname)
                qry.sql = strQry
            End If
            colGarbage.Add CurrentDb.QueryDefs(qry.Name), qry.Name
            .RowSource = qry.Name
        Else
            CurrentDb.QueryDefs(qry.Name).sql = strQry
        End If
'       Unselect the listbox entry
        .SetFocus                           
        .Selected(.ListIndex + 1) = False
        .Requery
        Me.Refresh

        Me.tbxListCount = .ListCount - 1
        .Visible = True

    End With
```

Comment: As far as I can tell you do not have to .setfocus to unselect an element in a listbox.  Also you should probably do that unselect before you change the rowsource shouldn't you?  Finally don't you need to check that an element is selected before you do .selected(.listindex+1)=false otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: Thanks Dan,
My empirical experience has been that unless the listbox has the focus, changing the selection row has no effect.

Comment: More to the last comment: IO have recently tried moving the change to before changing the row source. Once the ListIndex is changed, I cannot set the focus to the listbox or any other control for that matter. I get a 2118 error - must save the field before setting the focus. What field are we talking about? The listbox in question is unbound.

Comment: I tested this and had no problem changing the selected property without setting focus.

Comment: Where is your code above being called from?  The on-click event of a button or?

Comment: The routine is called at start-up on the listbox. The main menu has command buttons about entities (Like View/Edit Cars). The click event of the button on the main menu causes a class module (ButtonCarEdit) to be invoked. A second class module (Car) is invoked by ButtonCarEdit and the Car class module instantiates the (mCarFind) form. The form itself has an option group. Whenever the option group changes, the sql behind the list box is changed to provide the sort and filtering requested. There is also a search button; this, too, causes the sql to be changed for filtering.

Comment: More:There are three kinds of filters: text, value and date. Depending on the option selected in the option group one of the filter types is chosen, made visible and allowed to be filled in. There is also a clear button which completely sets up the list box again. 
Whenever the .ListIndex = -1 statement is executed, the focus can no   longer be moved from the List Box. The requery method stops working;  the form's refresh method won't work. Trying to set the focus to one of the filter textboxes fails. The errors are usually 2110 errors. Sometimes I get a 2118.

Comment: I finally got back to trying to make this work. Under no circumstance can I set the ListIndex to  -1 without the list box having the focus. After the focus is set to the listbox, I cannot set the focus back to the tbxSearchText, that starts things off in it after_update event.

Comment: I have completed debugging this problem. Thanks to everyone who answered. Here is a summary: To unselect the listbox, the listbox must have the focus then set ListIndex = -1 (Access 2013 try without foucs get Run-time error '7777'). Event handlers must protect against being re-entered. This is the main cause of not being able to move the focus.
A useful technique for solving this problem was to trace all the events in the Textbox.